# Search local OneNote and Web at the same time?

Tags: search, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

Is there a method to do a search in one place (browser or desktop) that can show me combined results for my local OneNote 2010 as well as do web results? For example, I can see my local OneNote hits when I do a Google search.

Is there a browser plugin or some other method to inject results from my local OneNote into my web search results? I know OneNote has an API, but I am not sure if this type of functionality exists for the Desktop (non-Web) OneNote 2010.